# Perl DBI MySQL Insert with both placeholders and foreign key

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I'm getting in a bit of a pickle with MySQL Perl DBI.  I have searched and can only find half the answer at a time and I don't know how to combine what I know to get the right answer.

I have several databases, one is the parent:

```
mysql> desc records;
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| File_Id  | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| fname    | varchar(59) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| type     | varchar(3)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| n1size   | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| downdate | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |               

mysql> desc mhqc;
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| MQ_Id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| fieldnum | tinyint(4)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| result   | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| File_Id  | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Records is filled in already and I want to add records into mhqc.  I am making a complete mess of my SQL statement!

The variables I need to insert (defined simply for simplicity) are:

```
my @fields = (1..41);  # this is for the fieldname column
my @results # 41 elements, contains results of checks performed on the fields 1-41
```

So, I want to loop over the number of results/fields:

```
INSERT INTO mphqc (MQ_Id, fieldname, result, File_Id) values (NULL, ?, ? ...
```

... and here I get stuck.  I obviously need to include some kind of select statement like the one below to tie everything together

```
SELECT File_Id from records where fname = \'$in_file';
```

I just can't find how to do both when the File_Id needs to be recorded in the child table.  Your help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can omit `MQ_Id` from the insert list and let it default. The other values need to be provided using a SELECT statement, and you need placeholders so that you can pass the parameters when you call `execute`.

Like this (untested)

```
my $insert = $dbh->prepare(<<__END_SQL__);
INSERT INTO mhqc (fieldnum, result, File_Id)
SELECT ?, ?, File_Id FROM records WHERE fname = ?
__END_SQL__

for my $i ( 0 .. $#fields ) {
  my $fieldnum = $fields[$i];
  my $result   = $results[$i];
  $insert->execute($fieldnum, $result, $in_file);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Borodin. I started trying all kinds of random nested statements and came up with something very similar.

Comment: I've just realised mine isn't working quite right yet, I am getting a NULL in the File_Id column     my $sql = 'INSERT INTO mhqc (fieldnum, result, File_Id) values (?, ?, (SELECT records.File_ID FROM records WHERE fname= ?))';   In fact I have edited the statement to match yours and I have the same issue.

Comment: @emmalg: Then there isn't an item in `records` that matches your file name. You can run this to check `print 'File_Id = ', $dbh->selectrow_array('SELECT File_Id FROM records WHERE fname = ?', undef, $in_file), "\n";`

Comment: Both statements seem to be valid and working.  The NULL  File_Id was because I needed to knock the file extension off the $in_file variable - oops - I think needed my lunch!  Thank you very much, your answer did help me as I wasn't using a placeholder for $in_file to start with.